# WkWebView viewport fit "cover" broken in iOS 12

Tags: cordova, wkwebview, ios12

We are having a problem in iOS 12 related to the viewport meta tag and hybrid apps (Cordova). Present only in X devices (no simulators), the viewport always shifts up on the first run of the app leaving a space below it as in the below screenshot. On the next run things are fine, but, as reported from by users, it can still happen in some rare occasions.

Our app is Cordova hybrid app and we implemented solutions for the X notch and bottom space using the safe-are-inset-* css rules along with the viewport-fit=cover meta tag.

https://app.box.com/s/r3atb8uoc4nghuckjahah4alayi9d0pd

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported as a bug to Apple, in OpenRadar site there is the reported radar:

https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5018321736957952

One way could be import this library:

https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard

Comment: The plugin keyboard I already use and I am now implementing the workaround for moving the viewport back in place when the keyboard goes away. However, this does not fix the extra space that appears at a first launch.

Comment: OK, so have you tried: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/417#issuecomment-432727776 ? Rough, to cancel when Apple will solve, but works